# Self hosted WCF Service not working when i type url in browser?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm new to wcf. I have Made simple self hosted service and added `app.config` but when I type address in the browser it is not showing me the service page that we get when we create our service `http://localhost:8067/WCFService` it is not displaying the service as it shows when we run service. But when i try to add base service in `public static void main` instead of `app.config` it works fine I'm not getting?? Can anyone please help me?

Following is the `app.config` file manually added:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="SelfHostedWCFService.WCFService">
                <endpoint 
                 address="http://localhost:8067/WCFService" 
                 binding="wsHttpBinding" 
                 contract="SelfHostedWCFService.IWCFService">
                </endpoint>
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Following is the Program.cs:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SelfHostedWCFService.WCFService));
    host.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Server is Running...............");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Following is the Interface file Manually added:

```
namespace SelfHostedWCFService
{    
    [ServiceContract]
    interface IWCFService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int Add(int a,int b);

        [OperationContract]
        int Sub(int a,int b);

        [OperationContract]
        int Mul(int a, int b);
    }
}
```

Following is the Service cs file Manually added:

```
namespace SelfHostedWCFService
{
    class WCFService : IWCFService
    {
        public int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            return (a + b);
        }

        public int Sub(int a, int b)
        {
            return (a-b);
        }

        public int Mul(int a, int b)
        {
            return (a*b);
        }
    }
}
```

Is something wrong with my `app.config` or some other concept??

Comment: sorry there is some typo its not succehttp://localhost:8067/WCFService its http://localhost:8067/WCFService

Comment: Forget about the browser. Does it work if you create a console application and use "Add Service Reference"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self hosted WCF Service not working when i type url in browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541925/self-hosted-wcf-service-not-working-when-i-type-url-in-browser)

Comment: @JohnSaunders: without any MEX endpoints, I doubt the Add Service Reference will work - right?

Comment: Right. I was trying to remove browser-specific behaviors from the question. For instance, browser will have proxies configured, "Add Service Reference" will not.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the meta endpoint to the self hosted service as well...

```
ServiceMetadataBehavior meta = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
      meta.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
      _host.Description.Behaviors.Add(meta);

      _host.AddServiceEndpoint(
        ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
        MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(),
        "http://localhost:8067/WCFService/mex"
      );
```

Comment: I think it's cleaner to do in the app.config, since there is already an endpoint in it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to import System.ServiceModel.Web to your Interface project, and add [WebGet] attribute for your OperationContract(s)

The interface would look as below:

```
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
namespace SelfHostedWCFService
{    
        [ServiceContract]
        interface IWCFService
        {
            [OperationContract]
            [WebGet]
            int Add(int a,int b);

            [OperationContract]
            [WebGet]
            int Sub(int a,int b);

            [OperationContract]
            [WebGet]
            int Mul(int a, int b);
        }
}
```