# Self hosted WCF Service not working when i type url in browser?

Tags: wcf, c#-3.0

I'm new to WCF. I have made a simple self hosted service and added `app.config` but when I type address in the browser it is not showing me the service page that we get when we create our service `http://localhost:8067/WCFService` it is not displaying the service as it shows when we run service.

But when I try to add base service in `public static void main` instead of `app.config` it works fine m not getting yy?? Can anyone please help me?

Following is the `app.config` file manually added:

```
<configuration>     
   <system.serviceModel>     
      <services>     
         <service name="SelfHostedWCFService.WCFService">     
            <endpoint
                address="http://localhost:8067/WCFService"
                binding="wsHttpBinding"
                contract="SelfHostedWCFService.IWCFService">     
            </endpoint>     
         </service>     
      </services>     
   </system.serviceModel>     
</configuration>
```

Following is the `Program.cs`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)     
{     
    ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SelfHostedWCFService.WCFService));
    host.Open();     
    Console.WriteLine("Server is Running...............");      
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Following is the interface file manually added:

```
namespace SelfHostedWCFService     
{      
    [ServiceContract]     
    interface IWCFService      
    {     
        [OperationContract]     
        int Add(int a, int b);      
        [OperationContract]     
        int Sub(int a, int b);      
        [OperationContract]     
        int Mul(int a, int b);
    }     
}
```

Following is the `service.cs` file manually added:

```
namespace SelfHostedWCFService
{     
    class WCFService:IWCFService     
    {     
         public int Add(int a, int b) { return (a + b); }      
         public int Sub(int a, int b) { return (a - b); }      
         public int Mul(int a, int b) { return (a * b); } 
    }     
}
```

Is something wrong with my `app.config` or some other concept??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems ok at first glance - are you **sure** the service isn't running??

Without any metadata being published, you cannot test the service using the [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx), nor can you generate a client-side proxy for it....

So I would recommend adding service metadata publishing to your service, and doing so, I was able to test that code of yours and it works just flawlessly.

To add metadata, change your config to:

```
<configuration>     
   <system.serviceModel>     
      <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
             <behavior name="Metadata">
                <serviceMetadata />
             </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
      <services>     
         <service name="SelfHostedWCFService.WCFService" behaviorConfiguration="Metadata">     
            <endpoint
                address="http://localhost:8067/WCFService"
                binding="wsHttpBinding"
                contract="SelfHostedWCFService.IWCFService" />     
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8067/WCFService/mex"
                      binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />     
         </service>     
      </services>     
   </system.serviceModel>     
</configuration>
```

Even with this config, you won't see any service page when navigation to the URL - but the service is up and running - just use the [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) and see for yourself!

Comment: thanks..... It needs endpoint for metadata exchange and base address . It worked!!